# How can I create a Hilt unit test case for SharedPreferences? I'm encountering a Hilt FilerException error while performing unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-hilt

I'm encountering an issue in my Android app while using Hilt for dependency injection. When I do UNIT TEST the project, I'm getting the following error:
[Hilt] Attempt to recreate a file for type

```
hilt_aggregated_deps._com_boltuix_code_MainActivity_GeneratedInjector: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type hilt_aggregated_deps._com_boltuix_code_MainActivity_GeneratedInjector
   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.checkNameAndExistence(JavacFiler.java:732)
   ...
```

**Hilt until class**

```
package com.boltuix.code.model.di

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object SharedPreferencesModules {

    @Provides
    fun providesSharedPreferences(context: Application): SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("DB1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

**my unit test code:**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import com.boltuix.code.utils.SharedPrefsUtilHilt
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidRule
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidTest
import junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import javax.inject.Inject

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class HomeFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPrefs: SharedPrefsUtilHilt

    @Inject
    lateinit var context: Context // If you need a context, you can inject it

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun testSharedPrefsSaveAndRetrieve() {
        // Write your unit test here
        // You can use sharedPrefs to save and retrieve data and make assertions
        sharedPrefs.save("testKey", "testValue")
        val retrievedValue = sharedPrefs.get("testKey", "")
        assertEquals("testValue", retrievedValue)
    }
}

.....................
package com.boltuix.code.utils

import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.util.Log
import com.google.gson.Gson
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class SharedPrefsUtilHilt @Inject constructor(val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) {
    val gson: Gson = Gson()
    private val editor = sharedPreferences.edit() // Create an editor for making changes to SharedPreferences

    /**
     * Save data to SharedPreferences.
     *
     * @param key The key under which the data will be stored.
     * @param value The value to be stored. Supported data types: String, Int, Long, Float, Double, Boolean, and custom data classes.
     */
    fun <T> save(key: String, value: T) {
        when (value) {
            is String -> editor.putString(key, value)
            is Int -> editor.putInt(key, value)
            is Long -> editor.putLong(key, value)
            is Float -> editor.putFloat(key, value)
            is Double -> editor.putLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value))
            is Boolean -> editor.putBoolean(key, value)
            else -> {
                val json = gson.toJson(value)
                editor.putString(key, json)
            }
        }
        editor.apply() // Apply changes to SharedPreferences
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve data from SharedPreferences.
     *
     * @param key The key of the data to retrieve.
     * @param defaultValue The default value to return if the key is not found.
     * @return The retrieved data or the defaultValue if the key is not found.
     */
    inline fun <reified T> get(key: String, defaultValue: T): T {
        return try {
            when (T::class) {
                String::class -> sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue as String) as T
                Int::class -> sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue as Int) as T
                Long::class -> sharedPreferences.getLong(key, defaultValue as Long) as T
                Float::class -> sharedPreferences.getFloat(key, defaultValue as Float) as T
                Double::class -> java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble(
                    sharedPreferences.getLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(defaultValue as Double))
                ) as T
                Boolean::class -> sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue as Boolean) as T
                else -> {
                    val json = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null)
                    gson.fromJson(json, T::class.java) ?: defaultValue
                }
            }
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            defaultValue
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clear all data in SharedPreferences.
     */
    fun clearSharedPreference() {
        editor.clear().apply() // Clear all data and apply the changes
    }

    /**
     * Remove a specific value from SharedPreferences.
     *
     * @param keyName The key of the value to be removed.
     */
    fun removeValue(keyName: String) {
        editor.remove(keyName).apply() // Remove the specified key and apply the changes
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a summary of all key-value pairs stored in SharedPreferences.
     *
     * @return A formatted string containing the summary of key-value pairs and their associated data types.
     */
    fun getAllSharedPreferencesDataSummary(): String {
        val summary = StringBuilder()
        val allKeys = sharedPreferences.all.keys

        Log.d("test", ".........................................")
        for (key in allKeys) {
            val value = sharedPreferences.all[key]
            val dataType = when (value) {
                is String -> "String"
                is Int -> "Int"
                is Long -> "Long"
                is Float -> "Float"
                is Boolean -> "Boolean"
                else -> "Custom"
            }
            summary.append("Key: $key, Type: $dataType, Value: $value\n")
            val logMessage = String.format("%-7s : %-15s ==> %s", dataType, key, value)
            Log.d("test", logMessage)
        }
        Log.d("test", ".........................................")
        return summary.toString()
    }
}
```

**FULL SOURCE CODE**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OXKPJ5XWbozb80OfkQeliETua8yfWOAz/view?usp=sharing

[image]